# Find the range of $f(x) = \frac{(x)}{(1+|x|)}$

Tags: functions

I tried splitting this function into two cases, when $x \ge 0$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x}$, and when $x \lt 0$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x}$. I thought I would take the union of the result that I would get by solving the two cases, but I couldn't solve it further. I found one way to proceed further, by using limits, but is there any other way?

Comment: This is a good start, you can derivate $\frac{x}{1+x}$ and find the variations of this function, same with $\frac{x}{1-x}$ respectively on $[0,+\infty)$ and on $(-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is odd and continuous for all $x.$ Thus, its range is of the form $(-c,c)$ for some $c>0.$ Hence, it suffices to find the range for $x>0.$ In that case we let $$y=\frac{x}{1+x}$$ and solve for $x$ to get $$x=\frac{y}{1-y}.$$ This is not valid for $y=1.$ Substituting $y=1$ into the original equation gives $x+1=x,$ which never happens, so that we obtain that our function is bounded above by $1$ (since it is continuous). Now, we proceed to finding the domain of the inverse for $x>0.$ Since $y>0$ in this case, we must have $1-y>0$ as well, so that the range of values of $y$ is $0<y<1$ whenever $x>0.$

It follows that the full range is $$(-1,1).$$

Answer (score 3):

On $[0,\infty[$, $f$ is strictly increasing. Since $f(0)=0$ and since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, $f\bigl([0,\infty)\bigr)=[0,1)$.

Therefore, since $f$ is an odd function, $f\bigl((-\infty,0]\bigr)=(-1,0]$.

So, the range of $f$ is $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $$-1 \le - \frac{|x|}{1+|x|} \le \frac{x}{1+|x|} \le \frac{|x|}{1+|x|} \le 1, \quad \text{ for all $x$}$$
- the limit of $f$ as $x \to \infty$ is $1$; the limit as $x \to -\infty$ is $-1$
- $f$ is a continuous function, so you can use the intermediate value theorem

Answer (score 1):

1) $f(-x)=-f(x)$ , i.e. $f$ is an odd function.

2) $x\ge 0$. $y:=f=(x)\ge 0;$

Solving $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$ for $x:$

$x=\frac{y}{1-y};$

We get $y \in [0,1)$ (Recall $x\ge 0$).

3)$x <0;$

Can you finish ? (See 1).